# How to compare strings and give a String output in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a tool to check different devices for their correct device information.
As you can see here the overall result is either appended or written down to the file as either 1 or 0.
What it should ideally be doing is appending or writing down PASS OR FAIL in this case 1 is pass and 0 is fail. can anyone give me a few suggestions on how I can achieve this. or if you professionals could give me an example code block that would be much appreciated too.

What I have tried so far:
I set `OVERALL_STATUS = 1` to `OVERALL_STATUS = PASS`  `OVERALL_STATUS = 0`
`DEVICE_TYPE_STATUS = 0` after else. but then it does not print the correct answer.
It prints "overall result PASS",
but it is actually supposed ot be "Fail"

PS: please go easy on me guys I and apologize in advance for not using the correct terms

```
OVERALL_STATUS = 1
STATUS_LIST = []
DEVICE_TYPE_STATUS = 1
DEVICE_TYPE_LIST = []

# Order number
print("Desired Order number:",d_ordernum)
print("Order number from scancode :",scan_code_cropped_artikel)
print("Ordernumber from wbm: ", ord_nmr)
if d_ordernum == ord_nmr == scan_code_cropped_artikel:
    print("Order number PASS")
else:
    print("Order number FAIL")
    OVERALL_STATUS = 0
    STATUS_LIST.append('Order Number FAIL')
print(100*"")

print("Desired device type:",d_dev_typ)
print("Device type from wbm: ", dev_typ)

if d_dev_typ == dev_typ:
   print("Device type PASS") 
else:
    print("Device type FAIL")
    OVERALL_STATUS = 0
    DEVICE_TYPE_STATUS = 0
    STATUS_LIST.append("Device type FAIL")
print(100*"")

if OVERALL_STATUS:
    print('Overall Result PASS')
else:
    print('Overall Result FAIL, ' + ', '.join(STATUS_LIST))



header = ["Timestamp:","Overall result:","Soll-orderno:","Desired-HW-Version:","Desired-SF-Version:","Desired-productcode:","Desired-device-type:","Scancode:","Wbm-orderno:","Wbm-HW-Version:","Wbm-SF-Version:","Wbm-mac-address:","combined-product-code:","wbm-device-type:","test-device-type:"]
toWrite = [
    [now ,OVERALL_STATUS,d_ordernum,d_hw_version,d_sf_version,pc_praefix,d_dev_typ,scancode_string,ord_nmr,v,b,mac_addr,product_code,dev_typ,DEVICE_TYPE_STATUS]
] 

file_exists = os.path.isfile(d_output_file)
    
if file_exists:
    with open (d_output_file, 'a') as f:
         writer = csv.writer(f)
         writer.writerows(toWrite)


if not file_exists:
    with open (d_output_file, 'a') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(header)  
        writer.writerows(toWrite)
```

output in the CSV file:

```
Timestamp:,Overall result:,Soll-orderno:,Desired-HW-Version:,Desired-SF-Version:,Desired-productcode:,Desired-device-type:,Scancode:,Wbm-orderno:,Wbm-HW-Version:,Wbm-SF-Version:,Wbm-mac-address:,combined-product-code:,wbm-device-type:,test-device-type:

2021-05-03 14:55:46,0,58184,1.0,1.0.0,7A2F7,TREE M-5TX PN IP67,58184#99AF0M000F9EF41A80,58184,1.00,1.0.0,00:0F:9E:F4:1A:80,7A2F7-1.0.0-1.00,TREE M-5TX PN IP67,1

2021-05-03 15:04:21,0,58184,1.0,1.0.0,7A2F7,TREE M-5TX PN IP67,58184#99AF0M000F9EF41A80,58184,1.00,1.0.0,00:0F:9E:F4:1A:80,7A2F7-1.0.0-1.00,TREE M-5TX PN IP67,1

2021-05-03 15:06:05,0,58184,1.0,1.0.0,7A2F7,TREE M-5TX PN IP67,58184#99AF0M000F9EF41A80,58184,1.00,1.0.0,00:0F:9E:F4:1A:80,7A2F7-1.0.0-1.00,TREE M-5TX PN IP67,1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your if else where you are printing pass or fail you can change the value of overall status with string or else you can create new variable and write that to the file

```
string_status = ''
if OVERALL_STATUS:
    print('Overall Result PASS')
    string_status = 'PASS'
else:
    print('Overall Result FAIL, ' + ', '.join(STATUS_LIST))
    string_status = 'Fail'
```

Now change the toWrite to:

```
toWrite = [
    [now ,string_status,d_ordernum,d_hw_version,d_sf_version,pc_praefix,d_dev_typ,scancode_string,ord_nmr,v,b,mac_addr,product_code,dev_typ,DEVICE_TYPE_STATUS]
]
```